# Advice on running a .war on a web server

Tags: tomcat, jboss, webserver

I have created a web application (.war) and I want to put it online. I need a server of course.
Do I need to buy a server that has jboss or tomcat on it?
When I get my server how do I run my .war file?

I have only ever bought hosting from sites like godaddy and all I needed to do was upload html or css files

I appreciate any advice :)

Comment: Do some googling, I was wondering this myself not long ago and its fairly simple to figure out. If you have a box you want to host on, yes all you need to do is install tomcat, plop the .war into the WebApplications directory, and start it up. Very simple. If you'd rather pay for a hosting service though, there are lots that run tomcat and / or jboss which you can just upload a .war to, maybe configure database connections with, and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a place that will host .war applications for free (temporarily), if you just want to get a feel for it.

http://www.eatj.com/

The apache documentation isn't the most straight-forward in the world for tomcat, but for the absolute basics of deploying a .war, really all you need to do is plop the .war into the $YOUR_TOMCAT_INSTALL_HOME/webapps directory and start the server, and it is off and running. If it doesn't seem to work, the log files should have exception messaging to clue you in on what went wrong.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/deployer-howto.html

Read there and google search for .war web application hosting to find places you can pay for rackspace / VMs, depending on what your traffic / security / integrations needs might be (Databases, Third Party APIs, Securities, Authorizations, Payments, etc)